# DataTable row with changed data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am developing one desktop based application. In that application I have to get only modified row to save/update in my database. for that I have used following code:

```
DataTable modifiedTable = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

that's fine. But here I have require only those column which is changed. I don't want that column which does not have any changes. So, I can log original value as well as modified/new value. (fetcher like Change Data Capture (CDC) in ms sql).

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OriginalValue and the Current version of the DataRow column values and then check if they are different

```
For Each row in table.Row
    For Each col in table.Columns
       Dim original = row[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString()
       Dim  changed = row[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current].ToString()

       ' Compare and prepare the SQL command to update only this changed column'
    Next
Next
```

But now you face a biggest problem. You need to write yoursef the code to update only that column.
(By the way this is one of the reasons to use a SqlDataAdapter and a SqlCommandBuilder)

[See the MSDN article on DataRowVersion enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kd9zhee%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)